# Cannot change Apple ID in App Store for downloading Yosemite

Tags: macos, app-store, updates, osx-yosemite

I want to download the latest version of Mac OSX (Yosemite). But, the app store doesn't let me change the user id for authentication.
Interestingly, I don't know whose apple ID is prepopulated into the text box. I have used my macbook all by myself until now!

[image]

I tried to logout and login again. But didn't work.
Does anybody know how should I fix this and download Yosemite?

Comment: Have you tried to press "Forgot" and afterwards logout/login ?

Answer (score 17):

The Problem is the way Apps are tied to IDs.

A step-by-step guide to solve this problem:

1. Go to the app listed in the App Store as needing an update (usually in the /Applications folder).
2. Right click the app then click “Show Package Contents”.
3. Go into the “Contents” folder, then into the “_MASReceipt” folder.
4. Delete the “receipt” file (you may need to enter a local administrator username and password).
5. Please note that the app will still work as intended.

Theres a pretty good explanation in here: http://www.valiant-ny.com/2014/06/grayed-out-apple-id-explained/

Comment: Your solution only works if the application is already installed on the system. I don't have Yosemite even downloaded on the system!

Comment: This is not a stasifying answear but: If you dont know whose Apple-ID this is, maybe you should do a clean reinstallation of your system?

Comment: worked for me after I deleted the "receipt" file for every app that wanted to be updated, closed appstore and restarted it

Comment: After deleting the “receipt” file, the app disappeared from the “Updates” tab...

Answer (score 1):

In the MacAppStore's task bar go to Store and then log out. Then try it again.

Comment: thank you, it worked on OS 10.10.5 (Yosemite), MacBook Air 13" Middle 2011

Answer (score 0):

(I have changed my ID to new one in Mac System.

Apple ICON > System Preference > Sign Out > New ID.

And then I changed the App Store ID like below.)

Open App Store
In the top main menu, Select Store > Logout
And the Sign In with new ID